# How to install either pybluez or LightBlue on OSX 10.9 (Mavericks‎)

Tags: python, bluetooth, lightblue

I have tried to install both of pybluez and LightBlue on OSX10.9 but I am getting error. 
Does anyone has managed to install any of these on Mavericks?

I am getting this error for LightBlue :

```
    === BUILD TARGET LightAquaBlue OF PROJECT LightAquaBlue WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
error: There is no SDK with the name or path '/Users/myname/Downloads/lightblue-0.4/src/mac/LightAquaBlue/macosx10.6'

** INSTALL FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
```

---

and I am getting this error for pyBluez :

```
    osx/_osxbt.c:676:5: error: unknown type name 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef'; did you mean 'IOBluetoothDeviceRef'?

    IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef inquiry;

    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    IOBluetoothDeviceRef

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Headers/IOBluetoothUserLib.h:34:47: note: 'IOBluetoothDeviceRef' declared here

typedef struct OpaqueIOBluetoothObjectRef *                     IOBluetoothDeviceRef;

                                                                ^

osx/_osxbt.c:688:17: error: unknown type name 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef'; did you mean 'IOBluetoothDeviceRef'?

                IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef inquiryRef,

                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

                IOBluetoothDeviceRef

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Headers/IOBluetoothUserLib.h:34:47: note: 'IOBluetoothDeviceRef' declared here

typedef struct OpaqueIOBluetoothObjectRef *                     IOBluetoothDeviceRef;

                                                                ^

osx/_osxbt.c:703:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryCreateWithCallbackRefCon' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

    dd->inquiry = IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryCreateWithCallbackRefCon (&dd);

                  ^

osx/_osxbt.c:703:17: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'IOBluetoothDeviceRef' (aka 'struct OpaqueIOBluetoothObjectRef *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]

    dd->inquiry = IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryCreateWithCallbackRefCon (&dd);

                ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

osx/_osxbt.c:705:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquirySetCompleteCallback' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

    IOBluetoothDeviceInquirySetCompleteCallback (dd->inquiry,

    ^

osx/_osxbt.c:717:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryStart' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

    IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryStart (dd->inquiry);

    ^

osx/_osxbt.c:721:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryDelete' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

    IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryDelete (dd->inquiry);

    ^

5 warnings and 2 errors generated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: When posting code, highlight the pasted code and click the `{}` icon. It'll improve the readability of it.

Comment: Hi Ben, sure thanks I will try to modify this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**PyBluez is windows only**:

"PyBluez works on GNU/Linux and Windows XP (Microsoft and Widcomm Bluetooth stacks)." - [pybluez homepage](https://code.google.com/p/pybluez/)

It looks like you're installing the **wrong version of LightBlue**

```
Check dependencies 
error: There is no SDK with the name or path '/Users/myname/Downloads/lightblue-0.4/src/mac/LightAquaBlue/macosx10.6'
```

it's looking for a file for OSX 10.6.

Download and install the master distribution: https://github.com/postskolkovo/lightblue-0.4

If you get the error:

```
Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=$(NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL), VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64).

** INSTALL FAILED **
```

you'll have to open up setup.py and change:

```
os.system("xcodebuild install -arch '$(NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL)' -target LightAquaBlue -configuration Release DSTROOT=/ INSTALL_PATH=/Library/Frameworks DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=YES")
```

to:

```
os.system("xcodebuild install -arch 'i386' -target LightAquaBlue -configuration Release DSTROOT=/ INSTALL_PATH=/Library/Frameworks DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=YES")
```

via [this discussion](https://github.com/postskolkovo/lightblue-0.4/issues/7)

**Edit**
I actually got a `ImportError: Bundle could not be loaded` on Mavericks when I tried to import.
This seems to be the fix for 64 bit computers:

```
os.system("xcodebuild install -arch 'x86_64' -target LightAquaBlue -configuration Release DSTROOT=/ INSTALL_PATH=/Library/Frameworks DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=YES")
```

Might be necessary if you come across the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

there is an other version which is especially for mac osx 10.8 https://github.com/0-1-0/lightblue-0.4. I can also run this version under osx 10.10 Yosemite.

I just had to follow the change the following line in the setup.py file:

```
os.system("xcodebuild install -arch 'x86_64' -target LightAquaBlue -configuration Release DSTROOT=/ INSTALL_PATH=/Library/Frameworks DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=YES")
```

and then i did insert the following two methods in  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lightblue/_lightblue.py :

def deviceInquiryDeviceNameUpdated_device_devicesRemaining_(self, sender, device, devicesRemaining):
    pass

def deviceInquiryUpdatingDeviceNamesStarted_devicesRemaining_(self, sender, devicesRemaining):
    pass

after the constructer of:

```
_AsyncDeviceInquiry(Foundation.NSObject):
```

the complete code is then:

```
class _AsyncDeviceInquiry(Foundation.NSObject): 

# NSObject init, not python __init__
def init(self):
    try:
        attr = _IOBluetooth.IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry
    except AttributeError:
        raise ImportError("Cannot find IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry class " +\
            "to perform device discovery. This class was introduced in " +\
            "Mac OS X 10.4, are you running an earlier version?")

    self = super(_AsyncDeviceInquiry, self).init()
    self._inquiry = \
        _IOBluetooth.IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry.inquiryWithDelegate_(self)

    # callbacks
    self.cb_started = None
    self.cb_completed = None
    self.cb_founddevice = None

    return self

def deviceInquiryDeviceNameUpdated_device_devicesRemaining_(self, sender, device, devicesRemaining):
    pass

def deviceInquiryUpdatingDeviceNamesStarted_devicesRemaining_(self, sender, devicesRemaining):
    pass
```

the last step is to alter this line in the same file:

```
deviceInquiryComplete_error_aborted_, signature="v@:@iB")
```

to

```
deviceInquiryComplete_error_aborted_, signature="v@:@iZ")
```

for me that works fine!

Hope that this is a helpful post.