# Error Installing lightblue on Mac 10.9.4

Tags: python, macos, core-bluetooth

I am trying to install lightblue (http://lightblue.sourceforge.net/) on a OSx 10.9.4, xCode 5.1.1
but when executing

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

I got this error:

```
=== BUILD TARGET LightAquaBlue OF PROJECT LightAquaBlue WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
error: There is no SDK with the name or path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk'
```

so the existings ones in my OSx are:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk
```

and

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk
```

Thanks !

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279913/how-to-install-either-pybluez-or-lightblue-on-osx-10-9-mavericks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [the latest version from GitHub](https://github.com/postskolkovo/lightblue-0.4).

You'll need to change [line 66](https://github.com/postskolkovo/lightblue-0.4/blob/master/setup.py#L66) from

```
os.system("xcodebuild install -arch '$(NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL)' -target LightAquaBlue -configuration Release DSTROOT=/ INSTALL_PATH=/Library/Frameworks DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=YES")
```

to

```
os.system("xcodebuild install -arch 'x86_64' -target LightAquaBlue -configuration Release DSTROOT=/ INSTALL_PATH=/Library/Frameworks DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=YES")
```

(Change `$(NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL)` to `x86_64`.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are supposed to follow the authors instruction in the read me file

### Installation for Xcode 1.5 / Mac OS X 10.3

The LightAquaBlue framework for the Mac OS X installation is in a .xcodeproj package which can only be opened by Xcode 2.1 and later, and Xcode 2.1 does not run on Mac OS X 10.3. So to build LightBlue on Mac OS X 10.3, just create a .xcode package yourself:

- Open Xcode and choose File -> New Project. Choose "Cocoa Framework" (under the "Frameworks" drop-down list) and save the project as "LightAquaBlue". Save the project anywhere as long as it's not replacing the existing LightBlue src/mac/LightAquaBlue directory.
- Go to Project -> Add files... and add all the .h and .m files from LightBlue's src/mac/LightAquaBlue folder. Also add the OBEXFileTransferDictionary.plist, OBEXObjectPushDictionary.plist and SerialPortDictionary.plist files.
- Go to Project -> Add framework... and add IOBluetooth.framework (found at /System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework).
- Click on the "Targets" item in the left-hand column of the Xcode window. This should show all the .h and .m files you've added as well as a few other files. In the "Role" column, all the .h files currently have "project" roles. Click on each drop-down menu item to change all of them to "public".
- Now go to the Finder and locate the xcode project you've just created. Copy the LightAquaBlue.xcode file for the project and paste it in LightBlue's src/mac/LightAquaBlue directory.

Now go to LightBlue's root directory and run the command

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

You should see the output of the build of the xcode project.

Comment: How does this answer relate to the OP's question about OS X 10.9?

Comment: He is currently having issues with LightAquaBlue project, which in many cases you have to go and manually create the project in xcode. At least that was my issue  with my current version 10.9.5