# Error when trying to install PyBlue on macOS

Tags: python, macos, pip

I've done `sudo easy_install pip`

Now I'm trying to install the library `pyblue` with `sudo pip install pyblue`

This is the error I'm having:

```
Password:
Collecting pybluez
  Downloading PyBluez-0.22.zip (109kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 716kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pybluez
  Running setup.py install for pybluez ... error
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-ZBL104/pybluez/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-TidHjG-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/bluetooth
copying bluetooth/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/bluetooth
copying bluetooth/ble.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/bluetooth
copying bluetooth/bluez.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/bluetooth
copying bluetooth/btcommon.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/bluetooth
copying bluetooth/msbt.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/bluetooth
copying bluetooth/osx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/bluetooth
copying bluetooth/widcomm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/bluetooth
running build_ext
building 'bluetooth._osxbt' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/osx
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c osx/_osxbt.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/osx/_osxbt.o
osx/_osxbt.c:676:5: error: unknown type name 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef'; did you mean 'IOBluetoothDeviceRef'?
    IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef inquiry;
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    IOBluetoothDeviceRef
/System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Headers/IOBluetoothUserLib.h:34:47: note: 'IOBluetoothDeviceRef' declared here
typedef struct OpaqueIOBluetoothObjectRef *                     IOBluetoothDeviceRef;
                                                                ^
osx/_osxbt.c:688:17: error: unknown type name 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef'; did you mean 'IOBluetoothDeviceRef'?
                IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef inquiryRef,
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                IOBluetoothDeviceRef
/System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Headers/IOBluetoothUserLib.h:34:47: note: 'IOBluetoothDeviceRef' declared here
typedef struct OpaqueIOBluetoothObjectRef *                     IOBluetoothDeviceRef;
                                                                ^
osx/_osxbt.c:703:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryCreateWithCallbackRefCon' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    dd->inquiry = IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryCreateWithCallbackRefCon (&dd);
                  ^
osx/_osxbt.c:703:17: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'IOBluetoothDeviceRef' (aka 'struct OpaqueIOBluetoothObjectRef *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    dd->inquiry = IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryCreateWithCallbackRefCon (&dd);
                ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
osx/_osxbt.c:705:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquirySetCompleteCallback' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    IOBluetoothDeviceInquirySetCompleteCallback (dd->inquiry,
    ^
osx/_osxbt.c:717:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryStart' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryStart (dd->inquiry);
    ^
osx/_osxbt.c:721:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryDelete' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryDelete (dd->inquiry);
    ^
5 warnings and 2 errors generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-ZBL104/pybluez/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-TidHjG-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-ZBL104/pybluez/
```

Not really sure what's going on and how to fix it.

Using easy_install seemed to give a similar error.

Question:

- Should I manually install pyblue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pybluez package (released 28-08-2015) you are trying to use is not supported on Apple operating systems.

From the [pybluez pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyBluez):

> Bluetooth Python extension module to allow Python ” “developers to use
>   system Bluetooth resources. PyBluez works ” “with **GNU/Linux and
>   Windows XP**.

[OSX support was added sometime between that release and September 10th 2015.](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/commit/65884eca182cd0a4973e33f310a812be4800e1cd#diff-88b99bb28683bd5b7e3a204826ead112R101)

At the time of writing pybluez still isn't tested with macOS (OSX 10.12), but if you did want to try and compile it by hand, you'd need [the latest source from Github instead](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez).

Comment: But the github page says it is

Comment: No really. It says that is **UNSTABLE**!!

Comment: @MauroBaraldi Please note that the pip package OP is using was released on 28th August 2015. At which point the README looked like this:- https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/195a1de06475a929004c167a39fefb2de2318379/README.rst , which *does not* list OSX support.

The bit about OSX support was added on 10th September 2015. Also note that macOS is 10.12, not the listed 10.10/10.11 from the README.

Answer (score 0):

According to [offical doc](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez):

> Mac OS X (Unstable - tested only on OS X 10.10/10.11):
>
> Python 2.3 or later
>
> Xcode
>
> PyObjc 3.1b or later (https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/install.html#manual-installation)

Perhaps, this another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279913/how-to-install-either-pybluez-or-lightblue-on-osx-10-9-mavericks) could help little bit more.

You could take a look at [LightBlue](https://github.com/0-1-0/lightblue-0.4), that is cross-platform, but is very outdated.